# Process Builder SOQL Limit Error

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, error-messages, bulkification, governorlimits

I am building a solution that tracks and logs timestamps for various tasks in our system.  I have built a flow in Process Builder to trigger based a couple conditions when a record is created or updated.  I'm getting a "Too soql queries" error though, that I cant wrap my head around.

Given that I'm only setting the trigger to fired and update a single record, I'm having trouble understanding how it is reaching a limit on soql queries.

I've added the flow, as well as the error message below.  Can someone help me understand this error message and how to remedy?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you running into this error when you insert or update a single `Task`, or do you run into it when inserting/updating multiple `Tasks`?

Comment: I'm getting the error message for both a single record or multiple-record update.

Comment: are there any triggers associated with that Task object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm only setting the trigger to fired and update a single record, I'm having trouble understanding how it is reaching a limit on soql queries.

Just like a trigger, Process Builder is subject to the same limits per transaction and must be created with "bulkification" in mind. If your PB processes 200 records in a transaction, all the triggers and process builders that can fire during that transaction context can only consume 100 SOQL queries. That 100 SOQL queries applies not only to your PB, but also to any other code that executes during the same transaction.

The issue you're having could actually be caused by other code if it's consuming all of your available limits before your Process executes. By the time it hits your Process, there may not be any SOQL limits available. Or, your process code could be what's pushing the transaction over the limit into the 101st query or beyond just as easily as it could be a case where the limits have already been exceeded. I say the latter because I don't see where your code has executed a query in what you've posted.

Here's are some links you may find helpful: [Salesforce Developer Limits Quick Reference Guide - Apex Governor Limits](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiT7YHUiL3SAhVFNiYKHYfSCawQFggKMAM&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNH9md0Nc70bFrLPDXglsl6k-yYTWA), [Flow Bulkification in Transactions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_admin_bulkification.htm?search_text=Bulkification) and [Limits for Visual Workflow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_admin_flow_limits.htm?search_text=governor%20limits).